# Removing leading text characters from string in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'fix_this_field':['dogstreet 1234, st, texas 57500', 'animal hospital of dallas, 233 medical ln '], 'needed solution':['1234, st texas 57500', '233 medical ln']})
df #look what i want
```

I want to extract all of the data after the first number, including the number.   See solution column in dataframe.  So something like 'hospital2019 lane' would become '2019 lane'.

I have tried looking something along the lines of what is below but I am struggling and banging head against the wall.  Please let me know error of my ways.

```
x = 'hospital2019 lane'
r = re.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)")
m = r.match(x)
m.groups()
# it stops at 2019.   I want 2019 lane.....('hospital', '2019')
```

Comment: Please show what you *did* get from this regex.

Comment: @Prune updated ty

Comment: maybe use for loop every character with try int() except? But this gonna be very slow if you have large dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy to achieve by using `split`

```
df.fix_this_field.str.split('(\d)',1).str[1:].apply(''.join)
Out[475]: 
0    1234, st, texas 57500
1          233 medical ln 
Name: fix_this_field, dtype: object
df['col']=df.fix_this_field.str.split('(\d)',1).str[1:].apply(''.join)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must use regex, below is an attempt:

- Regex: `(?:[a-zA-Z ])([0-9]+.*)`

```py
reg = re.compile('(?:[a-zA-Z ,])([0-9]+.*)')

def clean(col):
    return re.findall(reg, col)[0] if re.findall(reg, col) else None

df.fix_this_field.apply(clean)

Out[1]:
0    1234, st, texas 57500
1          233 medical ln 
Name: fix_this_field, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I found `df.fix_this_field.apply(lambda x: x[re.search("\d",x).start():])` and `df.fix_this_field.apply(lambda x: ''.join(re.split('(\d)',x,1)[1:]))` to be several times as fast as `df.fix_this_field.str.split('(\d)',1).str[1:].apply(''.join)`.